# How I can prevent of labels overlapping on mobile screen Chart.js

Tags: responsive-design, chart.js

I am using this example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Trekels/fec0v5kj/) on But When I use a small screen labels start to overlap like this

[image: overlap like this]

What I can do to prevent it ? I want to make it fully responsive. I tried to change length and other aspect ratios etc but no sucess.

```
    var ctx = $('#myChart');

ctx.height(500);

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @ℊααnd I disable responsive option in chart.js  and now added my own css . Somehow soloution working. But not 100%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be prevented by changing the y-axis label­*'s* font size on-the-fly *(dynamically)*. Though, in ChartJS there is no built-in method to do so, meaning no matter how you resize the chart, the font size will always be the same.

However, to get around this, you can use the following chart plugin, which will make the font size responsive ...

```
plugins: [{
   beforeDraw: function(c) {
      var chartHeight = c.chart.height;
      c.scales['y-axis-0'].options.ticks.fontSize = chartHeight * 6 / 100;
   }
}]
```

add this plugin followed by your chart options.

Here is a [**working example on jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/o0bu1Lnx/)

Comment: Can I ask one more thing ?

Comment: I want to show only tooltips of those , whose values are bigger then 9. I used callback for that but I think by default lable name mustly appear in tooltip. How I can remove that ? I read here on stack that it is not possible I have to write my own template for this ? And I didnt know how to use and make template .Any method ?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some CSS to stop the chart getting too small, forcing some users on mobile to scroll right:
https://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/yybc26Lr/1/

The only change I made was add

```
.chart{
  min-width:300px;
}
```

Comment: actually I have 42 records and I have to adjust on a Iphone 5 screen . Then obviously I need to compress this as well ? how I can do that ?