# How to scale label size radar chart chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I want to scale the labels in my radar chart because it is becoming very skewed and messed up on mobile devices , so I write this in `ComponentDidMount()`

```
const plugins = [{
    beforeDraw: function(c) {
        var chartHeight = c.chart.height;
        c.scale.pointLabels.fontSize = chartHeight * 6 / 100;
    }
}];

this.setState({ aggdata:data, options:options, plugins:plugins })
```

I attach this plugin to my radar chart like this:

```
<Radar
    plugins={this.state.plugins}
    data={this.state.aggdata}
    options={this.state.options}
/>
```

These are my options

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scale: {
        gridLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
        },
        angleLines: {
            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
        },
        pointLabels: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
            fontSize: "15"
        }
    }
};
```

But it is not working , any help or hint will be appreciated

**Edit attempt :**

```
render() {
        const show = this.state.render;
        if(show) {

        return ( <Radar  plugins={this.state.plugins} data={this.state.aggdata} options={this.state.options}/> )

        }
        else{
       return(<h3>Loading....</h3>)
        }

      
    }
```

Comment: when you say "onComponentDidMount()" are you referring to the `componentDidMount()` function of a components lifecycle?

Comment: @LuísMestre yes ,sorry for confusion i edit

Comment: i am afraid beforedraw has no effect ?

Comment: Yeah I aggre with @aryan-agarwal, it's probably because you're doing it on did mount when the component is already mounted. Try adding a new state like `loaded` that starts as `false`, and on did mount you'll change it to `true`, and the Radar component will only render when `loaded` is true

Comment: @LuísMestre can you guide me how to do this as I am getting lot of errors

Comment: @LuísMestre I attach my attempt see edited portion

Comment: @LuísMestre no it is working now but the error still remains data is skewed but you were correct now beforedraw is getting called as I see console log

Comment: I tried to see if I could find a working example and found this [Make Labels responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475563/making-the-labels-responsive-in-chart-js)
Although it's not a react component example, it explains in more detail how can chart.js have scalable font-size

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that you're using a class component, this is my suggestion

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            shouldRender: false, 
        };
    }

    get options() {
        return {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scale: {
                gridLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
                },
                angleLines: {
                    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)"
                },
                pointLabels: {
                    fontStyle: "bold",
                    fontSize: "15"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    get plugins() {
        return [{
            beforeDraw: function(c) {
                var chartHeight = c.chart.height;
                c.scale.pointLabels.fontSize = chartHeight * 6 / 100;
            }
        }];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const data = // ...your data
        this.setState({ data, loaded: true })
    }


    render() {
        const { data, loaded } = this.state;
        if (!loaded) return <h3>Loading....</h3>;

        return (
            <Radar
                data={data}
                plugins={this.plugins}
                options={this.options}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code, but I ask you @aryan-agarwal to try it and if it gives any error whatsoever to comment pls

Comment: Thanks for your effort but code is already working but beforeDraw has no effect on font size maybe you can guide me with that